# Legend tag does not display

Tags: html, css

I try the `<legend></legend>`tag in html, but it does not display at all. 
I reviewed W3school [legend tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset) and it does not seem to be a deprecated tag.
Why the style of the tag (the bordert that passes through the word that I write) does not show like in w3school example?

```
<form>
<legend>Form Input</legend>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML and possibly the CSS that you are using?

Comment: Post the code that you're using, so we can help you better

Comment: are you using a CSS reset or normalize css ?

Comment: I want to have the same effect that appears in w3scool example of the legend tag; the line border that passes through the word that I write inside the legend tag

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Yes, a normalize is included, and I tried to shut it off by commenting the link tag and still did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `<fieldset>` around `<legend>` and all of the content inside the `<form>`. Here is your better code:

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
<legend>Form Input</legend>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

w3schools does also say this in the editor